# Does maven execute module by module or phase by phase

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin, maven-3

For a multimodule project how does maven executes?

- Does it execute module by module. I mean does it complete all phase on the first module. Then complete all phase in the second module and so on.

or

- Does it complete a single phase on all modules then run second phase on all modules and so on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module by module.  maven invokes all the relevant life cycle phases specified by the command on each module, one after the other.  Also read the [guide to working with multiple modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)

Answer (score 1):

Maven first parse all multi-module tree. Checks dependencies. 
If project B dependence on project A project A is build first. The order from `<module>` has second priority.

And one general rule - always add `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>` to child poms.

You can not have cycles.

Comment: So module A will complete all its phases then module B ? as per Raghuram said.

Comment: Yes, module A finished all the phases. Modules are not built in parallel.